# Why do i get "Argument is not optional" error on simple url call?

Tags: vba, connection

My goal is to check the internet connecton in VBA but when i try to call a url with request.open I get the error message "Argument is not optional".

Sadly internet research has no yielded any results.

This is my code:

```
On Error GoTo NoConnectionErrorHandling
    Dim Request As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Request.Open "http://www.google.com"
    Request.send
    MsgBox Request.Status
```

It hangs itself in the third line of the shown code. 
I hope someone can help me as i have very very little experience in VBA yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the request. It can be "GET", "POST" or something else.

See here for the open Method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849(v=vs.85).aspx

These are the parameters:

- **bstrMethod**
  The HTTP method used to open the connection, such as GET, POST, PUT, or PROPFIND. For XMLHTTP, this parameter is not case-sensitive. The verbs TRACE and TRACK are not allowed when IXMLHTTPRequest is hosted in the browser. [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)
- **bstrUrl**
  The requested URL. This can be either an absolute URL, such as "http://Myserver/Mypath/Myfile.asp", or a relative URL, such as "../MyPath/MyFile.asp".
- varAsync[optional]
- bstrUser[optional]
- bstrPassword[optional]

As you see, the method needs at least two parameters (the other 3 are optional) thus 1 is not enough.

You need to declare `Request` with the keyword `New`. Thus, something like the following piece works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim Request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Request.Open "GET", "http://www.bbc.com"
    Request.send
    MsgBox Request.Status    
End Sub
```

---

Whenever you are using libraries outside the standard VBA libraries it is a good idea to do one of the following 2:

- Provide information for the library:

[image]

- Use late binding:

---

```
Dim Request As Object
Set Request = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

Comment: I have tried this and i dont get an error message anymore, but strangely it fails and goes into the ErrorHandler altough there is a perfect internet connection

Comment: @MansNotHot - see the edit. `Google` is a site, that does not allow being cralwed by anybody that easily. `BBC.COM` has no such resctriction. Furthermore, you should declare `Request` with the keyword `New`.